# Range of a complicated function

Tags: functions

Is there any way to figure out the range of values of the function $$y=\frac{2}{x}\cdot \sin(x)?$$ The domain is so easy to know. It's all real numbers except $0$. However the challenging part is to figure out what is the range. Any ideas?

I know that I need to know the minimum & maximum values that the function $y$ can get but no idea how to figure that out.
All I know is that the possible values of $\sin(x)$ alone is from $-1$ to $1$ but the complexity comes from that part $2/x$ which I don't know what to do when this part is multiplied by $\sin(x).$
Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\dfrac{2}{x}\cdot \sin x$ or $\dfrac{2}{x\cdot \sin x}$?

Comment: Hints: $|\sin x|\le|x|$, $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, $f'(x)=2\dfrac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}=0 \Longrightarrow \tan x = x$.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I caused. I meant: (2/x)*sin(x)

Answer (score 1):

You indicate that your function is $\frac {2 \sin x}x$.  Since $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {2 \sin x}x=2$ the upper end of the range is $2$, but it won't get there.  To get the minimum, we take the derivative and set to zero:  $0=\frac d{dx} 2\frac {\sin x}x=2\frac {x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}$ or $x=\tan x$  You can't solve this algebraically, but can solve it numerically. [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x=cot%28x%29) gives an approximate solution of $4.4934$ witha a value of about $-0.4345$, so the range is $(\approx -0.4345,2)$

Answer (score 0):

Often it is quite difficult to know the range of functions.  You can plot it and [look](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%282%2Fx%29%2asin%28x%29), but that might be misleading if the plot is not representative.

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming that you mean $\frac{2}{x}\sin(x)$: note that for $x << 1$, $\sin (x) \sim x$, i.e, for $x = 0$ you have $y = 2$. Then, for $x \rightarrow \infty$, $y \rightarrow 0$. What is left is to look at the derivative around 0 to make sure that $x = 0$ is a local (and global) maximum